# C# equivalent of C++ mem_fun?

Tags: c#, methods, delegates, mem-fun

I'd like to do something like the following in C#:

```
    class Container {
        //...
        public void ForEach(Action method) {
            foreach (MyClass myObj in sequence) myObj.method();
        }
    }

    //...
    containerObj.ForEach(MyClass.Method);
```

In C++ I would use something like std::mem_fun.  How would I do it in C#?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This ought to work, in C# 3.0:

```
class Container 
{        
//...        
public void ForEach(Action<MyObj> method) 
{            
    foreach (MyClass myObj in sequence) method(myObj);        
}    
}   

//...    containerObj.ForEach( myobj => myObj.Method() );
```

Comment: Thanks, that does the trick.  (Unfortunately it still creates garbage which is why I didn't just return an enumerator, but that's another story.)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that:

```
    public void ForEach(Action method) {
        foreach (MyClass myObj in sequence) method(myObj);
```

is no good for you, then I think you're stuck with reflection.